# reactively fetch new data from external source on action button

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny

My goal is to retrieve data from a googlesheet and map it on a leaflet map.

Everything is working fine, only if the code to retrieve data from googlesheet is placed in the global.R and it is only valid for that session of the running shiny app.
 However, if meanwhile the sheet is updated, these updates are not reflected in the running session. **So I need to wire up a ui.R button to fetch new data each time the button is fired and pass the data onto the relevant codes in server.R .** (I hope this is clear).

In my current setup, the data gets downloaded from googlesheet (via **global.R**) and passed on to the environment and used for that running app session.

Here is my working shiny app setup:

### ui.R

```
...
leafletOutput("map"),
actionButton("button", "Get New Data")
...
#added the below lines to update the question:
                        selectInput("Country",
                                    "Country:",
                                    c("All",
                                      unique(as.character(draw$Country))))
```

### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
#... 
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
#... some options here
})
  draw <- mydata
  drawvalue <- reactive({
    if (input$year == year1){return(mydata)} else {
      filtered <- filter(mydata, Type == input$type1)
      return(filtered)
    } 
  })
  observe({
#... some other variable definitions
    colorBy <- input$color  ##added to update the question
    sizeBy <- input$size   ##added to update the question

    draw <- drawvalue()
    colorData <- draw[[colorBy]]  ##added to update the question

#... code related to the leaflet
  })
#...
}
```

### global.R

```
mydata <- gs_read(gs_key("0123456abcdabcd123123123"))
```

After some reading and exploring, I am told that I have to use reactive and observeEvent. But my faulty setup results in error, saying that 'object "mydata" not found'.

I tried in the server.R: (I know the code below is all faulty)

```
observeEvent(input$button,{
mydata <- gs_read(gs_key("0123456abcdabcd123123123"))
})

mydata <- eventReactive(input$button,{
mydata()
})
```

### update:

in my ui.R, I also refer to "draw", this also bugs. How should I change this one? I updated the lines in the ui.R above in the question. this line is part of the ui.R line which call the DT package to show some tables.

by the way, this app is based on the superzip shiny app.
**NB: I will give 100 points bounty for the accepted answer.**

Comment: This seems like a job for a `reactivePoll`/`reactiveFileReader`, does the connection to google docs have a lightweight check to see if the data has been modified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general `observe` and `observeEvent` do not return any value and they are used for side effects. So this part of the code below doesn't return any value and even if you used `<<-` to override the variable `mydata` shiny wouldn't know that its value has changed.

```
observeEvent(input$button,{
mydata <- gs_read(gs_key("0123456abcdabcd123123123"))
})
```

So if you want shiny to know when the data is updated you should read it within reactive environment. So, instead of reading the data via global.R I would advice to do following within `server.R`:

```
mydata <- eventReactive(input$button, {
    gs_read(gs_key("0123456abcdabcd123123123"))
  })
```

After clicking the button shiny would read (new) data which could be then accessed with `mydata()` and passed to the `render*` functions and other reactive parts of the code. For example:

```
drawvalue <- reactive({
  if (input$year == year1){return(mydata() )} else { # added () 
    filtered <- filter(mydata(), Type == input$type1) # added () to mydata
    return(filtered)
  } 
})
```

You had to change this part of code

```
draw <- drawvalue()
```

to

```
draw <- reactive({ drawvalue() })
```

and then access it with `draw()`

---

**UPDATE**:

If you want make choices of the widget `selectInput` from UI.R dependent on `draw` you can do following:

1) Add the parameter `session` to the server function for `updateSelectInput`

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {...} # added session
```

2) Set choices of the widget in UI.R to ""

```
selectInput("Country", "Country:", choices = "")
```

3) Update the choices on the server side with:

```
observe({
    req(draw()) # require that draw is available
    updateSelectInput(session, "Country", "Country:",
                c("All", unique(as.character(draw()$Country))))  # added ()
  })
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this step by step explanation! it seems to advance, but a bug still prevents me seeing the results ... I updated my question by adding a bit that bugs and prevents the app from running: I have a variable `colorData <- draw[[colorBy]]`, this bugs! and in ui.R, I call `draw$mycolumn1`, this also bugs.

Comment: i am sorry, I forgot the last line of your answer that i should access it with draw(), it is working!!! thanks!

Comment: however, the line of code which uses `draw` in the ui.R, still bugs! how to call access `draw` from ui side?

Comment: I updated my answer and I hope it will solve the problem with `draw` :)

Comment: thanks, the ui.R part is working. perfect! Actually I accepted your answer and the bounty system will be available in two days, and then I will start the promised bounty on it and it will be automatically attributed to your answer. cheers!
however, the variables solution that you mentioned, I couldn't set it up! I just added () to all instances of draw to access it as you mentioned already. I suppose it is working! apparently! however, I would like to learn the way you suggested. is it possible that I send you my entire server.R (via pastebin or chat) for you to help me with it?

Comment: It seems I misunderstood that part of the code. I'll be on stackoverflow chat (public R) in one hour and will be ther for about an hour

Comment: sure i will be waiting, meanwhile here is the link to my server.R http://pastebin.com/VZ20Uqcc

Comment: i don't know how to open a chat conversation. please let me know if you know how to do it.

Comment: I am here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public
If you join the room I'll create a new conversation